# Getting focus on a gridview item by default - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gridview

I am loading 6 imageviews in my gridview as shown in the code below. I have 2 queries:

(1) When I launch the application, I need to have the first image view selected by default.
(2) I am setting a listener which will launch some other activity, from each of the 6 items in the gridview. When I return from the 2nd activity, I need to retain focus on the item which was selected.

How can I achieve these two requirements?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
// Main activity
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);  
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setOnItemClickListener() - pos:" + position);
            handleItemClick(position);
        }
    });



//class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter

// Keep all Images in array   
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher, 
        R.drawable.ic_launcher,
};

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(160, 120));
    return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
gridview.setSelection(position); // position = 0 or wherever you wants
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I tried it before posting this here. It did not work. I do not understand why!